# Pinch Gesture Segue in/out of ViewController

Tags: objective-c, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I currently have an [ICarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) view with about 5 subviews.

I'm looking for a way to give the user the ability to pinch (out) on one of the view and a new `UIViewController` slowly grow/expand from the middle of that view.
It would start off tiny and grow as the gesture gets wider and wider.

Once the new `UIViewController` is fully on the screen or more then halfway, it will animate to fit the screen and become active.

Then when the user pinches (in) same thing happens in reverse.

Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Comment: First off, requests for library recommendations are [not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) on Stack Overflow. If you've made attempts to implement your pinch recognizer and the segue to a new view controller on your own and need help solving a specific problem with it, please post the code for what you've tried already. If you haven't tried to solve it yet, re-read the previous sentence for a hint on how you could.

Comment: I can make the gesture and the transition I just don't know how to gradually show the transition with the pinch data.

Answer (score -1):

If you're just having trouble creating a custom transition animation, I'd recommend googling "[UIViewController custom transition](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/)."